# CSS list-style-type not working

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have set the `list-style-type` in CSS, but for some reason it's not showing it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ol {
  list-style-type: decimal;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Check your margin and padding...

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Because of your padding reset, the numbers are actually off to the left of the page. Try adding:

```
list-style-position: inside;
```

Answer (score 34):

```
display:list-item;
list-style-position:outside;
```

It may give problem if list `display:` attribute is set to some thing else than `display:list-item;`

Answer (score 6):

Decimal is default for an "ol". No need to declare it. Also the numbers are there just falling off the side of the page i.e. invisible. Adjust your padding and get rid of the redundant declaration. [See here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I always thought some browsers use different styles, and the ol style type may vary, that's the reason why I put it there.

Comment: from w3c "Ordered and unordered lists are rendered in an identical manner except that visual user agents number ordered list items. User agents may present those numbers in a variety of ways. Unordered list items are not numbered."

Comment: If he happens to be using a CSS reset file beforehand, the ol may be set to a different value

Answer (score 4):

If nothing of this work, make sure you don't have elements explicitly marked as display block inside the LI. It just happened to me with a H4 A set as block inside the LI. I was about to resign

Answer (score 3):

In my case it wasn't working with `<ul>`.

I suspected it was possibly because of a CSS reset file I was using.

I set the `ul { display:list-item; }` as suggested above, and it just worked fine.

Check if you are using any reset files.  They could be tricky at times.

Comment: Try this with `list-style-position: inside;` & `list-style-type: disc;`

Answer (score 2):

just remove "display : block;" from your li element

Answer (score 0):

Changing properties of `<li>` instead of `<ol>` worked for me.

```css
ol > li {
  padding: 0;
  display:list-item;
  list-style-type: 'disc';
}
```