# List points in css will not work

Tags: css, list

I created a box in css and put text inside of the box. I would like it to be a list. However, when I try to use it messes up the formatting of the entire page. I also tried the solution here: [CSS list-style-type not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447611/css-list-style-type-not-working), but that didn't work either. My original code is below. My question is, is it the list- style or the box that I created that might be giving me the problem?

```
<p class = "total" style= "background-color: #C6C29E;opacity:.9;height:2000px;width:500px;float:left;color:black;text-shadow: 4px 0px #aaa;list-style-type:circle;">
<li>Text</li><br>
    <li>Text<br></li>
 </p>
```

Thanks

Comment: When you have unexpected rendering problems, use the validator:  http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thanks. I have never seen that, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Joseph. It's a bad idea wrapping a `<p>` tag around an `<li>` element and using `<br>` tags this way. You should use CSS to style the content rather than using the `<br>` tags to do it for you.

If you're wanting to just add list items into its own self expanding box [does this help at all](http://jsfiddle.net/EP8m8/) or is this not quite what you mean?

```html
<ul class="my-list">
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul.my-list {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Agree in a comment, this isn't an answer.

Comment: Apologies, I was looking to do that however there doesn't seem to be a button to comment on other answers for some reason.

Comment: You need a higher reputation, you'll get it soon.

Answer (score 2):

To create a list, you have to wrap your `li` items in either a `ul` or a `ol`:

```
<ul class="total" style="list-style-type:circle;">
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Besides, there would be no need of `<br>` threre. Is it even allowed?

Comment: So, everything you said makes sense, but it still doesn't work. Lets say I am on my page and I have a block with text in it. When I add the list, it literally moves all the text outside of the box and moves anything else on the page to different positions. I even tried moving all the background color and font styling to css. Is there something else I could try? Thank