# Make div as list-items, with div not having the same parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make multiple divs to be shown as list item. But the sequence of that divs is not guaranteed. It can be under any other parent div like the following code

```css
.list-item {
  display: list-item;
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-item">
  <p>ABC</p>
</div>

<div class="no-list-item">
  <p>DEF</p>
</div>

<div class="heading">
  <div class="list-item">
    <p>XYZ</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want similar kind of result for above code.
[image]

Comment: They are not in the same container so this way it wont work. Otherways https://css-tricks.com/custom-list-number-styling/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `list-style-position: inside` for show the numbers, as well explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12447651/4031083

But I think isn't possible to have an item not in the same level, probably the browser rendering can't know if it is part of the same list.

```css
.list-item {
  display: list-item;
  list-style-type: decimal;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-item">
  <p>ABC</p>
</div>

<div class="list-item">
  <p>ABC</p>
</div>

<div class="no-list-item">
  <p>DEF</p>
</div>

<div class="heading">
  <div class="list-item">
    <p>XYZ</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

This can be a possible solution:

[MDN for further information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)

```css
.fake-ul {
  counter-reset: section;
}
.list-item {
  display: block;
}

.list-item::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section) ".";
}
```

```html
<div class="fake-ul">
  <div class="list-item">
    <p>ABC</p>
  </div>

  <div class="list-item">
    <p>ABC</p>
  </div>

  <div class="no-list-item">
    <p>DEF</p>
  </div>

  <div class="heading">
    <div class="list-item">
      <p>XYZ</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: from where does the value of section is coming?

Comment: @NeelDsouza `section` is a name of variable, you can change it as you want. `counter-reset` set it to `0` and every `counter-increment` add `+1` to your variable (here `section`). The MDN link in my post is a good guide.